# Neo4j SDN prepopulate entity

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have a following Neo4j SDN entity:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Comment {

    private final static String COMMENTED_ON = "COMMENTED_ON";
    private final static String CREATED_BY = "CREATED_BY";

    @RelatedTo(type = COMMENTED_ON, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Commentable commentable;

    private String text;

    @RelatedTo(type = CREATED_BY, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private User author;

}
```

and a following SDN repository method:

```
@Override
@Query("MATCH (c:Comment) WHERE id(c) = {commentId} RETURN c")
Comment findOne(@Param("commentId") Long commentId);
```

As a result of this method invocation I have `Comment` object with `author.id` only.

How to change this method(or Cypher query) in order to prepopulate `author.name` also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have to annotate the author field with `@Fetch` (which fetches the full author eagerly.

Or you can call `template.fetch(comment.author)` if needed case by case.